# Problems with installing packages using rpm package manager

Tags: centos, rpm

I am currently trying to install packages on CentOS based machine which doesnot have yum, so I need to use rpm for installation. I grabbed the required rpm pacckages and try to install it like this

```
$ rpm -Uvh cpp-4.9.3-199192.h1.aarch64.rpm libmpc-1.0.1-3.aarch64.rpm
warning: cpp-4.9.3-199192.h1.aarch64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 255f3799: NOKEY
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        installing package libmpc-1.0.1-3.aarch64 needs 200KB on the / filesystem
        installing package cpp-4.9.3-199192.h1.aarch64 needs 15MB on the / filesystem
```

I queried the packages for where they will be installed and found following:

```
$ rpm -ql cpp-4.9.3-199192.h1.aarch64.rpm
warning: cpp-4.9.3-199192.h1.aarch64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 255f3799: NOKEY
/usr/bin/cpp
/usr/lib/cpp
/usr/libexec/gcc
/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.9.3/cc1
/usr/share/info/cpp.info.gz
/usr/share/info/cppinternals.info.gz
/usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/cpplib.mo
/usr/share/man/man1/cpp.1.gz
```

and

```
rpm -ql libmpc-1.0.1-3.aarch64.rpm
warning: libmpc-1.0.1-3.aarch64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 255f3799: NOKEY
/usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3
/usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libmpc-1.0.1
/usr/share/doc/libmpc-1.0.1/COPYING.LESSER
/usr/share/doc/libmpc-1.0.1/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/libmpc-1.0.1/README
```

However, even after succesful installation I cant find the any file related to my new packages in the locations above. I don't have much experience with CentOS before. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

[Edit]
After using `rpm -Uvh cpp-4.9.3-199192.h1.aarch64.rpm libmpc-1.0.1-3.aarch64.rpm`:

```
$ which cpp
/usr/bin/which: no cpp in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3': No such file or directory
```

Comment: How does the system not have `yum`? If that's the case then you're going to have a very hard time installing any packages that have dependencies because `rpm` won't find and pull them automatically so you'll have to find and install them one by one. If those packages installed successfully then the files will be there or else `rpm -ql` wouldn't return anything. Add the output  of `which cpp` and `ls -l /usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3` to your question.

Comment: `$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3': No such file or directory`

`$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib64/libmpc.so.3': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Edit your question and add the output there so that it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: I understand the complexity so trying to install `yum` either using a rpm file or building from source.